How can I make a soft brush blend well with already painted areas?
In canvas js, the brush does not blend well if you paint it on a hidden canvas first, over already painted areas.
You can draw without a hidden layer, directly on the main canvas, but then you will not be able to make transparency using ctx.globalAlpha.
The brush borders are clearly visible above the already drawn image. You can reduce the number of steps, then the halo effect will not be noticeable, but I need many steps.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas Brush Example</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

    <script>

        function createBrush(size, color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)', hardness = 0.1) {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            const blur = size / 2 * (1 - hardness);
            const canvasSize = size + blur * 2;

            canvas.width = canvasSize;
            canvas.height = canvasSize;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(canvasSize / 2, canvasSize / 2, size / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.shadowColor = color;
            ctx.shadowBlur = blur;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fill();

            return canvas;
        }

        function drawLine(ctx, brush, startX, startY, endX, endY, brushSize, step = 10, alpha = 1) {
            const distance = Math.hypot(endX - startX, endY - startY);
            const steps = Math.ceil(distance / step);
            const deltaX = (endX - startX) / steps;
            const deltaY = (endY - startY) / steps;

        const tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');

            for (let i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
                const x = startX + deltaX * i;
                const y = startY + deltaY * i;
                tempCtx.drawImage(brush, x - brushSize / 2, y - brushSize / 2, brushSize, brushSize);
            }

        ctx.globalAlpha = alpha
            ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1
        }


        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const brushSize = 40;
        const color = 'rgba(0, 136, 255, 1)';
        const hardness = 0.01;
        const brush = createBrush(brushSize, color, hardness);

    //frist line, step 0.01, brush hardness 0.01
        drawLine(ctx, brush, 50, 100, 250, 100, brushSize, 0.1);

    //second line, step 0.01, brush hardness 0.01   
        drawLine(ctx, brush, 50, 100 + brushSize / 2, 250, 100 + brushSize / 2, brushSize, 0.01);


    </script>
</body>
</html>

here screenshot   two lines, and visible border in middle.
